# I use jdk8 but Spring told me I need jdk5 or higher

Tags: java, spring, version

In .java

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
```

I got

> 1.8.0_45

but when I packed it as a jar package and use it in another project it told me

```
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml];
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource
[applicationContextYQ.xml]; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element
'component-scan' and its parser class
[org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser]
are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher
```

why?

in cmd

> C:\Users\idea>java -version
>
> java version "1.8.0_45"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: How do you pack and compile it?

Comment: Have you checked your `jdk` version in IDE project ?

Comment: @SanKrish 1.7 for this project

Comment: Are you sure ? And which IDE you use ? check for compiler settings

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO export > jar file > select all content in this project > finish

Comment: @SanKrish eclipse luna, I can run this project alone  and  nothing goes wrong but when I packed this  it told me java version is too low and component-scan can`t be used

Comment: Make sure you are using a Spring version that is actually supported on Java8. So in short which Spring version are you using..

Comment: @M.Deinum in pom.xml  
  `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Don't add code, xml etc. as comments. Improve your question with that information. Also check your libraries with `mvn dependency:tree`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this code to the pom.xml of your project:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.3</version>
 <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <compilerArgument />
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And also have this to include all dependencies on your JAR:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

And have assembly.xml under src/assembly (or change the path as you wish):

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: I have this conf , I think  eclipse don`t packed the dependence into jar so the jar is  too small

Comment: try add this to the assembly.xml:


`<files>
 <file>
  <source>*.xml</source>
  <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
  <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
 </file>
 <file>
  <source>*.config</source>
  <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
  <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
 </file>
</files>`